# I have an International Driving Permit (1949 convention) issued on July 1 2022: is it valid until June 30, 2023 end of day or July 1, 2023 end of day?

Tags: international, driving, travel, geneva-convention

Also, end of day in which time zone? Country of issuance or country where one is currently located?

I read the 1949 [Geneva Convention on Road Traffic](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Geneva_Convention_on_Road_Traffic) but didn't see the answer.

Comment: Good question but there is likely not a definitive answer.  It may depend on the country or even the locality where you are and how THEY interpret the expiration.  Why risk it?  Just renew it in advance and then you won't have to worry yourself.   Most likely, however, is that the expiration takes effect at the end of the day WHERE YOU ARE at the time.

Comment: If is valid for one year, and is valid on July 1, why do think the last day of validity isn't on the following 30th June? In the case of insurance cover, in UK the certificate states the time too, so it might be valid from 12:01pm on 1st July to 11:59am on the next 1st July.

Comment: From the [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/travel/comments/110a4wt/i_have_an_international_driving_permit_1949/) post, ask yourself if the police officer who looks at the permit when you are driving on 1st July 2023 is going to say "Oh... you are right. I checked with my sergeant so we know that it is still yesterday in [your own country]. On your way, and have a nice day! We think you can drive until 15:00 hours but is it on DST?"

Comment: @WeatherVane agreed about the time zone but I prefer to have legal sources when possibly instead of relying on my common sense.

Comment: What I am trying to ask is whether you can expect an officer of the law who confronts you to be reasonable, and whether in the long run it will be easier to renew the licence (or take a taxi on that day) than create a situation which might only be resolved after a great deal of trouble. In many countries, one does not point out to an officer of the law why they are wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane sure, but still useful to know the law. Also IDPs aren't just for police officers.

Comment: ... even if you are right.